# Writing Code for a Simple Responsive Header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a responsive header for my website. Ideally, on a large screen the logo will be to the left, and an inline menu of three items will be to the right. When you view it on a small screen, I would like the logo centered at the top, and the three menu items stacked and centered.

I have two problems. First, I'm having trouble aligning the inline menu with the logo. I have the logo set to margin:auto but when I set the text menu to that, it pushes itself to the very top of the page. I manually adjusted the top margin but noticed that it changed based on the device screen size (duh), therefore it's not vertically aligned with the logo at all times. I want it to be vertically aligned with the logo at all screen sizes.

The second issue is when I view it on a small screen, the text menu is stacked under the logo, but it's not centered and I can't figure out why.

The issue of the stacked menu not centering kept happening so I started over from scratch and still ran into the issue.

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  }


ul {
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: 'Literata', serif;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     }

li {
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:transparent">
    <img src="imglink" style="max- 
     width:100%;height:auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:transparent;">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu">MENU</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Ah, you mean adaptive header (not responsive header)!

Answer (score 1):

Try display **Flex** Or use one of the front-end component libraries for example **bootstrap**

```css
  li {
    list-style: none;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
}
img.image {
    width: 120px;
}
.menu ul {
  display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu ul li{
    padding: 0 8px
}
.menu {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  .logo {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="header">
  <div class="column logo">
    <img class="image" src="imglinkg">
  </div>
  <div class="column menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu">MENU</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <style>
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .column {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: transparent;
            flex: 1;
        }

        .column img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        // makes side by side div's same height
        .row {
            display: flex;
        }

        // makes nav-div's content vertically centered
        #nav {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        ul {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: 'Literata', serif;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            display: inline;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
            // for big screens, make links appear side by side
            li {
                float: left;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .column {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                margin: auto;
                float: none;
            }
            li {
                text-align: center; //centers links
                display: block; // makes links appear on top of each other, not side by side
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="imglink">
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu">MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
´´´
```